# In Angular , Can we have common App Module or can we have individual Module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

My colleague and I had conversation about to setup our application using Angular js.

I was saying we can create a global common Module App (ex: employeeApp) this will be used by all of its modules used in the whole application. So if any common injection has to happen, then we inject those in Common Module App and we don't need to inject into individual Module.

But his point was not to create global Common Module App. Because
   1. Global Variable which will be complained by javascript tools(ex : jshint).
   2. Wanted to make every Module as Independent. If any issues happening in a particular module it won't affect others.

How do you see this approach. Which one is better over the other one. ?

Comment: No need for a global variable.  I can provide an example if you want but I think I am not understanding your question.

Comment: Why don't we need to global variable? it will avoid repetition of injection in another module..

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of modules is to increase ***testability***.

With this in mind, more, smaller modules is better, as each one can be better unit tested.

Comment: I would also add that reusability is equally important.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I setup my angular code without globals.

```
// app.js
(function(angular) { 'use strict';

  var zaysoApp = angular.module('zaysoApp', 
    ['ngResource','ngRoute','zaysoApp.personModule']);

})(angular);

// person.js
(function(angular) { 'use strict';

  var personModule = angular.module('zaysoApp.personModule', []);

  personModule.factory('personFactory', [ function()
  {
    return { create: function(data) { return new Person(data); }};
  }]);
})(angular);
```

So the main app modules just needs to know the name of each individual module.

I don't really understand your question but I do know that globals are not needed.